# Weird shapes and lines on solid shapes and low light on cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]I'm new to blender and I have been using blender cycles the lighting is weird and low in my render and another issue is that my shaped are glitching out and showing random lines and shapes on solid objects. I thought It was connecting all vertices but I tested it by remaking the object but no luck.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean, it is not clear what the issue is, and please keep only one question per post, if you have multiple problems post them separately.

Answer (score 2):

From your picture, the shape glitching looks like [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). This happens when you have two objects (or faces of the same object) that occupy the same space. If it is Z-fighting, it will probably flicker when you move around in the viewport.

To fix it, try moving the object around. You can also try going into Edit mode, selecting all the vertices, and pressing `W` > [Remove Doubles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#remove-doubles). (This is also good to do just on general principle—even just canceling a Shift+D will create duplicate vertices in the same spot.)

I don't know about the lighting issue; can you post a picture of the rendered view so I can see what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The lines are coming because of the scene clipping value maybe.You can change it here:[image]
Generally it should be 10cm and 100km then it should work fine and for the low lighting maybe you can change it in world settings.[image]

Comment: Each scene may need its own values for clipping, but 10 cm for low clipping and 100 km for high are crazy values for probably any scene out there. It's also not clear how is the world lighting related to clipping in the scene.

Comment: but those clipping values might solve the problem and the world lighting is not for clipping,its for the low light in the scene which is asked to be corrected in the question.

Comment: As a general rule, clipping distance should be set to a range that fits the scene, no more, no less. Having an extremely large range means less precision and might yield to Z-fighting errors..